# Need help to add 64bit MMAP device in dtb

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

Could someone help to enable 64bit register mmap device to ARM64 linux kernel dtb.
In my platform linux kernel device driver, *(*res)->start* uses 1st entry of '*reg*' dtb and *resource_size(*res)* uses 2nd entry of '*reg*' dtb.

```
dev: dev@8000000000 {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "nxp,dev-1.0";
        reg-names = "dev0", "dev1";

        reg = <0x00000080 0x00000000 0x01FFFFFF>,//Inst0 0x80_0000_0000 to 0x80_1FFF_FFFF
              <0x00000080 0x50000000 0x01FFFFFF>;//Inst1 0x80_5000_0000 to 0x80_6FFF_FFFF
        interrupts = <0 170 0>;
        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
};
```

**Driver:**

```
    *res = platform_get_resource_byname(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, name);
    if (*res == NULL) {
            dev_err(device, "resource %s not found!\n", name);
            return -ENODEV;
    }

    printk("sizeof((*res)->start) %d \n", sizeof((*res)->start));
    printk("sizeof((*res)->end) %d \n", sizeof((*res)->end));

    printk("\n\nNAME %s, (*res)->start 0x%llx, resource_size(*res) 0x%llx dev_name(device) %s \n\n", name, (*res)->start, resource_size(*res), dev_name(device));

    region = devm_request_mem_region(device, (*res)->start,
                                     resource_size(*res), dev_name(device));
```

**Log:**

```
sizeof((*res)->start) 8
sizeof((*res)->end) 8


NAME dev0, (*res)->start 0x80, resource_size(*res) 0x0 dev_name(device) 80.dev

80.dev: unable to request dev0
request_and_map() failed for dev0
sizeof((*res)->start) 8
sizeof((*res)->end) 8


NAME dev1, (*res)->start 0x1ffffff, resource_size(*res) 0x80 dev_name(device) 80.dev

80.dev: unable to request dev1
```

Comment: There should be nothing to add to support 64-bit registers in DT.  Your DT node has the properties `#address-cells = <2>;` to indicate that a reg <address> value will consist of *two* <u32> values, and `#size-cells = <1>;` to indicate that a reg <size> value will consist of *one* <u32> value.   So "**(res)->start uses 1st entry of 'reg'*" is incorrect/incomplete, as it needs to also grab the 2nd <u32> value.  "**resource_size(res) uses 2nd entry of 'reg'*" --  No, it's the 3rd <u32> reg value that is for the size.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's how I'd expected to behave the same in my driver but my driver uses aforementioned way, that's why I am surprised and seek help to see if any mistake I made.

Comment: What is the `#address-cells` property for the parent node of this dev@8000000000 node?  Seems like it's only <1> when you need to have it at <2>.  FYI the `#address-cells` property defaults to <2> if not defined.  IOW you need to show more of your DT instead of just one node without any context.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for the hint. Actually I'd declared this dts entry inside 'soc' property and it worked after declaring the same entry out of 'soc' property. thanks much for the help.

Comment: I suspect the length of your register regions should be 0x02000000, not 0x01FFFFFF.